# Need advice what method or algorithm to use for calculating topology matrix for node voltage method in matrix form

Tags: programming, nodal-analysis

I want to make a program that will calculate everything in a scheme with the node voltage method in matrix form.

The problem is I don't know really how to do this.

I want to translate this scheme with this edges to the matrix A0.

edges=[(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4),(4,1)]

A0=[

[1,0,0,-1,1,0],

[-1,1,1,0,0,0],

[0,0,-1,1,0,-1],

[0,-1,0,0,-1,1],

]

Could someone tell me what algorithm or law to use in this situation?

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Systems/Electrical/mna/MNA1.html

Comment: http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/mna/MNA1.html